# Data filter from sql database

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table like this:

```
1.    26-01-15   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       45675      
2.    26-01-15   0   0   5100    0   0   0   0       50775      
3.    26-01-15   0   3000    0   0   1000    24000   0       28775      
4.    26-01-15   0   0   0   925     0   0   0       29700      
5.    27-01-15   0   0   2925    0   0   0   0       32625      
6.    27-01-15   0   1000    0   0   0   0   0       33625      
7.    27-01-15   0   0   0   950     0   0   0       34575      
8.    28-01-15   0   0   4850    0   0   0   0       39425      
9.    28-01-15   0   6500    0   0   0   0   0       45925      
10.   28-01-15   0   0   0   650     0   0   0       46575
```

But I want to display the data like this:

```
1.    26-01-15   0   0    0    0     0   0   0       45675      
2.    26-01-15   0   3000 5100   925 1000    24000   0       29700            
3.    27-01-15   0   1000 2925   950     0   0       0       34575
```

i.e I want to merge line of single date into one, Except the first date ie., 26-01-15 which is the opening balance. How do I do this?

Even my table stores data as seen in the 1st table..

Comment: Your sample output has two lines for the same date, this appears to contradict your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` clause in your table; Your query will be :

```
select column1, column2, column3....
from table_name
order by date_column 
group by date_column
```

To select all records from table

```
select * from table_name
order by date_column 
group by date_column
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you meant by `filtering one column`?
If I understood your problem correctly, then you need to use order by also

Comment: This is what i got1.    26-01-15  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    45675      
2.    27-01-15  0  0  2925  0  0  0  0    32625      
3.    28-01-15  0  0  4850  0  0  0  0    39425      
4.    29-01-15  0  0  3850  0  0  0  0    50425      
5.    30-01-15  0  0  3725  0  0  0  0    55625      
6.    31-01-15  0  0  1075  0  0  0  0    60250

Comment: Buddy, please check your `data` again and the `expected output`. Your sample output has two lines for the same date, this appears to contradict your statement, though you are saying `I want to merge line of single date into one`

Comment: Good; You removed it :)
Hope, Now you will get the correct result.

Comment: yes only the 1st date 26 will be twice since the 1st one is openong balance..apart from that all other only once

Comment: Okay...
Then you can put the first records as it is and apply the query for remaining records.
You have to include something like `select except top 1 from table_name` and the above query... (in a single query) to do it

Comment: This is what i want
2.    26-01-15   0   3000 5100   925 1000    24000   0       29700            
3.    27-01-15   0   1000 2925   950     0   0       0       34575

Comment: but i am getting
2015-01-26 |        0 |     0 | 45675 |    0 |      0 |       0 |    0 | 0
   1 |     0 | NULL |
2015-01-27 |     2925 |     0 | 32625 |    0 |      0 |       0 |    0 | b-3
   5 |     0 | NULL |
2015-01-28 |     4850 |     0 | 39425 |    0 |      0 |       0 |    0 | b-4
   8 |     0 | NULL |

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `field_name1`,`field_name2`,`field_name3`,.... 
FROM `table_name`
ORDER BY `date_field_name`
GROUP BY `date_field_name`;
```

If you want to list the whole table, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name`
ORDER BY `date_field_name`
GROUP BY `date_field_name`;
```

This query will group and order fields according to the `date_field_name` field.